# Custom CSS won't override default bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new in HTML and CSS and I'm stuck here...

Website is: http://www.i1cevic.com/

Basically, the 'bold text' won't be the `font-size` I defined in my CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 1.05;
letter-spacing: -2.7px;
font-size: 89px;
}




h1 small {

font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: -2.7px;
font-size: 70px;

}
```

The class I'm having problem with is `h1`, as you can see `font-size` is defined as `89px` but it keeps showing Bootstrap's default `h1` size : `35-36px` or something, I went past this issue by writing `!important` after `font-size: 89px` but that's not the solution...

Here's the HTML code. (not including head section)

```
<body id="page-top">
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <h1><small><font color="black">Light Text</font></small></h1>
        <h1><font color="black">Bold Text</font></h1>
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" href="#about">Find
        Out More</a>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js">
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->

<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js">
</script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->

<script src="js/creative.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked this "jquery.fittext.js" script that resizes the text depending on the size of the page, and so natural that you have this problem. This script adds the tags "h1" the "font-size".

Comment: Read the OP's question. `I went past this issue by writing !important after font-size: 89px but that's not the solution...`

Comment: I had not read that part, but now I've added the solution below.

Comment: This is it! Thank you all!

Comment: especially like to thank the two geniuses that have commented on my solution in a negative way, but it did not help ...

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont see in your code where you use your own css file.
2. That's why I defined css in your head part:

   h1 { font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1.05; letter-spacing: -2.7px; font-size: 89px; }
3. And I remove styles from yours h1 tags.

   font-size: 65px;

Comment: thanks for reply! As I replied above, actually my stylesheet is under bootstrap default CSS but I didn't included it in html copy/paste, thanks again and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the head section, you need to place your bootsrap css link first, then you link to your custom css, like this :

```
<!-- first your bootstrap link-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- second your custom css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

good luck

Comment: thanks mate for fast reply, actually my stylesheet is under bootstrap default CSS but I didn't included it in html copy/paste, thanks again and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed your inline style and I could see your style overridiing bootstrap style

so I think it's your browser cache try to clear cache or do hard reload `ctrl+shift+R`if your are using windows and chrome 
of `cmd+shift+R` on Mac OSX

[image]

Answer (score 0):

inspecting it now there's style attributes in your markup

[Screenshot: dev tools showing inline style setting size to 65px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDkgV.png)

A look at the source shows it's not there so one of your scripts is adding it in.

Comment: and as @peppinoibra points out, the script that's doing it is `jquery.fittext.js` which is resizing every thing based on the window width.